# Bootstrap Multiselect plugin fails to uncheck all elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-multiselect

I am using [Bootstrap Multiselect plugin](http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect) for my select option elements. When user select one (or all options) from one select option element, all elements from other select options element needs to be unchecked. I checked documents for solution and when I use code in documentation I got error:

```
bootstrap-multiselect.js:1042 (Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function)
```

Does someone knows where's the problem?

Here is my code:

```
 $('#select1').multiselect({
        includeSelectAllOption: true,
        enableFiltering: true,
        onChange: function(element, checked) {
            //alert ("OK");//Alerts pop ups
            $('#select2').multiselect('deselectAll', false);
            $('#select2').multiselect('updateButtonText')

        }
    });
```

Comment: Did you add jquery and bootstrap before the multiselect plugin? Can you show in which manner you added your scripts? Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27103898/bootstrap-multiselect-typeerror-multiselect-is-not-a-function might help if your problem is similar.

Comment: @Sourabh-, of course he did - the error would never be raised otherwise.

Comment: The code works fine, there is no bug in multiselect -> http://jsfiddle.net/0te0cjde/.  In the future, please provide markup and preferable also a fiddle or a link to a site where we can see what actually is happening.  An answer to the above question would be pure guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to recreate your issue by removing jQuery and bootstrap. Since all bootstrap really does is style it you can use the plugin without it (it just looks really bad) and it will not throw any errors.

Removing jQuery will throw the following errors:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined
index.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
```

I looked at the latest version of `bootstrap-multiselect.js` and the 1402 line is blank so I do not know where that error is coming from.

Line 1401 is:

```
}(window.jQuery);
```

My guess is you are using an older version of the plugin although that is probably not causing the issue. Try [updating the plugin](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect/master/dist/js/bootstrap-multiselect.js) to see if that does anything.

*Please note I tested this on jQuery 2.1.3 using the latest version of bootstrap-multiselect on Chrome v41 Mac OSX 10.10*

Answer (score 1):

In older versions of the plugin, line 1042 looked like

```
+1041            if (typeof option === 'string') {
+1042                data[option](parameter);
```

And the option `deselectAll` was named `deselectall`, which would cause error in this line. If you need to use this version of the plugin, simply replace the option to `deselectall` and it will work fine. But I strongly recommend you to update to the last version.

FWIW, the first version of this plugin in GitHub already has this function as `deselectAll`, so this version is really old, and I couldn't find it to show as reference. But I had this same problem here in my workplace, and the version we used to work with was probably the same as OP has.

```
+823    /**
+824     * Deselects all options.
+825     * If justVisible is true or not specified, only visible options are deselected.
+826     * 
+827     * @param {Boolean} justVisible
+828     */
+829     deselectall: function (justVisible) {
 ...
```